# Enable bluetooth configuration in a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, embedded, bluetooth, buildroot

Basically I'm trying to enable bluetooth in my Raspberry Pi 4 using **buildroot 2022.08**.

Since I want to use **bluetoothctl** command I already enable the **bluez-utils** package and the respective firmware configuration, however when I boot my board and after instantiate the hci_uart module, if I run the bluetoothctl command the system returns me that "command not found".

Can buildroot be made to work with bluetoothctl properly?

Comment: I'm confused. In comments to your closed question on [so] you said you're using Ubuntu 22.04 ... however, there's no package called `bluez-utils` for jammy, neither do any packages for Jammy contain a file called `bluetoothctl` ... And what's the correlation between **my Raspberry Pi 4** and **when I boot my board**?

Comment: I was referring to the OS on which I have buildroot installed. I am using buildroot to generate a linux image for me that I then copy to the Raspberry Pi 4 using an sdcard. In the buildroot settings there is a package called bluez-utils available, which supposedly enables the use of the bluetoothctl tool. However when I copy the image to the Raspberry Pi the command does not work. When I referred to ```my board``` I meant my Raspberry Pi 4. Basically I wanted to refer that after the Rasp boot I install the necessary kernel modules.